# Wordpress Custom Template with Additional Field

Tags: php, wordpress, portfolio

I created my own  custom Wordpress template:

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file for display portfolio page.
 *
 * Template Name: Portfolio Test
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
*   Get Current page object
```

I want to this page showing portfolio by its categories, if the selected category is children, than the page will show the children photos.

How to add a field when I select this template at admin page, the field to input the category slug to define this page will show what category.

How to add the category slug field?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd recommend not doing it this way, Wordpress uses the same page for each blog category, e.g. index.php. When you navigate to a category it is displayed by the same page each time. Seperate blog categories seems like the long way round to me.

But you can add a custom field to posts like this

```
    <?php
      function custom_field_meta( $meta_boxes ) {
          $prefix = 'custom'; // Prefix for all fields
          $meta_boxes['custom_field_metas'] = array(
              'id' => 'custom_field_metas',
              'title' => 'Custom Field Details',
              'pages' => array( 'post', '' ), // post type
              'context' => 'normal',
              'priority' => 'high',
              'show_names' => true, // Show field names on the left
              'fields' => array(
                  array(
                      'name' => 'Blog Category',
                      'desc' => 'choose category to display',
                      'id' => $prefix . '_cat',
                      'type' => 'text'
                  ),
              ),
          );

          return $meta_boxes;
      }
      add_filter( 'cmb_meta_boxes', 'custom_field_meta' );
```

And use the output like with this code

```
    <?php global $post;
        $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_cat', true );
        echo $text;
    ?>
```

Then in the query use the custom meta, something like this:

```
    <?php
    $loop = new WP_Query( 'category_name=
         <?php global $post;
           $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_cat', true );
           echo $text;
         ?>
      ' );
    ?>
```

Some caveats: I've not used this code and suspect the custom_meta won't work in the wp_query as it needs to be inside the loop; the custom field would need to have the slug input perfectly or it won't work.

Right so, what should you do? Set up a page for your blog, "our Blog" or something. Go into Wordpress settings "reading" and select "our Blog" as your posts page. Then go to appearance > menu and create a menu that links to your blog categories (if you can't see categories to link to, click screen-options and check "categories").

Good luck.

Comment: Surely this isn't correct, as if you download a boilerplate theme such as BlankSlate, that contains the template file `category.php` which is automatically used to display blog categories, and stays well away from `index.php`.

Comment: It is theme dependent yes - [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)